# Existence Of Congruent Triangles

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

Two triangles $ABC$, $XYZ$ are "good" when $AB=XY$, $AC=XZ$, $\angle ABC=\angle XYZ$.
That is, when two segments are equal and a not-included angle is equal, they are "good".

There are $n$ triangles. $(n>3)$
$1$st triangle is good with $2$nd triangle.
$2$nd trianlge is good with $3$rd triangle.
$3$rd triangle is good with $4$th triangle.
...
$n-1$ th triangle is good with $n$ th triangle.

Show that there exist congruent two triangles out of them.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with this problem statement, the way it is stated it is enough to show that there are two congruent triangles between the first four triangles. There is no need for $n$. May be the problem statements says triangle $n$ is good with triangle $1$.